# Running appium script on glass

Tags: c#, android, appium

I am trying to test an app written for glass using Appium. When I run my script it successfully loads the apk. The problem I run into is it takes me to an authentication prompt for the app. If I register my pair of glass prior to starting the appium test, it will disconnect me since running the test re-installs the apk every time. Is there a work around so that I can have my test script just launch my main activity without re-installing the apk every time?
I am using Appium within C# along with Specflow. 
Lastly, is there anywhere that someone can point me to to show me what all the list of desired capabilities are in the C# environment?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hey Andrej , could u please help me and tell me how did u integrate specflow with Appium ?  please. Thanks

Comment: Arpan I would be glad to help but can you be more specific? I used it in my step definitions file and made the appium driver an instance variable that could be shared with all the step methods. Let me know if that answers your question and if it doesn't let me know what you are having problems with and I will try and help you.

Comment: Hey , please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768576/appium-unable-to-run-script-in-multiple-android-device-connected

Comment: Arpan, sorry I did not respond earlier. I read your thread that you referenced but I am not familiar enough with it to be of any help. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! just go to Android settings in appium and select "No Reset" option, this will not reinstall the app when you re-run your test.

Comment: I found a workaround for my specific problem. I found the "No Reset" option in Android settings and tried it but it didn't work. I am wondering if it behaves differently with Google glass as opposed to a regular android device. It shouldn't though. On a side note, if I set the capabilities in my test code but have different settings done through the Appium GUI do you know which one wins out?

Comment: @Andrej; Are you running your appium test with android studio? If yes, then capabilities set in test code works. Also, you can add capabilities for no reset in your test code itself. I have added in my test code and it works.

Comment: @Surman I am running my tests from Visual Studio. I will try o set the capability from my code because I do not think it works when I set it in the Appium GUI.

Comment: do you know if the apk has to be installed on the machine where appium server is installed? What I mean is, what if I want to run appium on a remote machine and have another machine actually build/run the test code. Is there any way the apk can be on the machine that is building and running the test code?